# Multiple srun on a node (non-exclusive) and wait for completion

Tags: slurm, hpc, csh, sbatch

I have an sbatch script that looks like this (each node has 128 cores):

```bash
#!/bin/tcsh
#SBATCH --nodes=5

srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt1
srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt2
srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt3
srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt4
srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt5
srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt6
srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt7
srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt8
srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt9
srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt10

srun -n 640 ./program.x
```

The first 10 `srun`s all run sequentially and, when finished, execute my larger program.  The first 10 `srun`s *could* all execute at the same time, then wait for them to finish, then execute the final larger `srun`.  However, my nodes are set up to be exclusive, so right now I could probably have 5 going at a time, but it would be much more efficient to have them all going at once in a non-exclusive manner because they do not depend on each other.  I also don't know which will take the longest, and it will change based on several factors on the cluster.

What `srun` options do I need to use to get all of my `srun`s to run simultaneously then wait until they are all complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can typically do this in a loop by backgrounding the processes and waiting at the end, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
#SBATCH --nodes=5

foreach i ( `seq 1 10` )
    srun -n 1 -c 1 ./exec opt${i} &
end
wait

srun -n 640 ./program.x
```

You may need to add other options to the single core `srun` options (e.g. specify `--exact`) to get them all to run in parallel and/or pin to different cores but that depends on your local Slurm and system configuration so you consult your local documentation/support on exactly what options are needed.